# How To Make A Hexacopter With Ardupilot In AirSim?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, airsim

I am using AirSim, and I need a hexacopter with Ardupilot based firmware. Documentation exists on how to do this with PX4, but not Ardupilot. How would I go about making this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your project in Visual Studio, navigate to `Plugins/AirSim/AirLib/include/vehicles/multirotor/firmwares/arducopter/ArduCopterParams.hpp`
Find the `setupParams()` method, and replace `setupFrameGenericQuad(params);` with `setupFrameGenericHex(params);`

And set your Ardupilot FRAME param to hexacopter (this can be done in QGroundControl)